# xslt to add default value where element doesn't exist

Tags: xslt

I'm struggling with trying to test to see if an element exists. If it doesn't, I'd like to add in a default value. Here's my XML

```
<records>
  <record>
    <InstanceData>
      <instance>
        <FirstName>Johhny</FirstName>
        <LastName>Jenkins</LastName>
        <AlbumCount>3</AlbumCount>
      </instance>
    </InstanceData>
  </record>
  <record>
    <InstanceData>
      <instance>
        <FirstName>Art</FirstName>
        <LastName>Tatum</LastName>
        <AlbumCount>7</AlbumCount>
      </instance>
    </InstanceData>
  </record>
  <record>
    <InstanceData>
      <instance>
        <FirstName>Count</FirstName>
        <LastName>Basie</LastName>
      </instance>
    </InstanceData>
  </record>
</records>
```

I'd like to be able to copy over existing values and set any record without the Album Count element to `<AlbumCount>0</AlbumCount>`. This is the xslt I've been working with but I think I'm some way off the mark.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0"> 
  <xsl:template match="Records">
    <xsl:for-each select="node()">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="name()='AlbumCount'">
          <xsl:element name="AlbumCount">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="name()='AlbumCount'">
                <xsl:copy-of select=".">
                </xsl:copy-of>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <AlbumCount>0</AlbumCount>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:copy-of select=".">
          </xsl:copy-of>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks for looking.

Comment: What output are you currently getting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

<!-- identity template -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="instance[not(AlbumCount)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <AlbumCount>0</AlbumCount>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Start with the identity transformation, then just handle the exception differently.

Comment: @Dimitre - taa for the big up!

Answer (score 3):

You test for the existance of an element simply with the elements name, for example:

```
<xsl:if test="not(AlbumCount)">
  <AlbumCount>0</AlbumCount>
</xsl:if>
```

The simpler way to do what you want is to use the standard copy template combined with a special rule for places where AlbumCount elements need adding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- Standard copy template -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Special template to add AlbumCount elements where required -->
  <xsl:template match="records/record/InstanceData/instance">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      <xsl:if test="not(AlbumCount)">
        <AlbumCount>0</AlbumCount>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @Kragen I'm bowing to Dimitre's request but still a big thanks for coming up with a working solution!